# Gulp - compiled css file not generated in directory I want

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

Im using `gulp 3.9.1` to compile `scss`. It compiles fine, but the not outputting the compiled `css` in the `dest` directory. Here's my `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require("gulp-sass");

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src("/scss/*.scss").pipe(sass()).pipe(gulp.dest("./css"));
});
```

Instead, the compiled `css` being generated in the same folder as the source `scss` file. Whats my mistake?

The structure of my folders is as follows:

```
-root
     -css (the desired destination of the compiled css)
     -node_module
     -scss
         -style.scss
         -style.css (should'nt be here!!)
     -gulpfile.js
```

Comment: `./` refers to `current folder`. Remove the dot.

Comment: Thanks, but `pipe(gulp.dest("/css/"));` produces the same output. I mean, in the same directory as the source

Comment: `return gulp.src("./scss/*.scss").pipe(sass()).pipe(gulp.dest("./css"));`, assuming your gulpfile in in the root folder, will work.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you, can you please see the edit of my post? I'm trying to get the compiled `css` file into the folder `css`.

Comment: `return gulp.src("./scss/*.scss").pipe(sass()).pipe(gulp.dest("./css"));` should work given your folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the destination folder as 'css' instead of './css'. I have just tested and it is working for me like you expected:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require("gulp-sass");

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src("/scss/*.scss").pipe(sass()).pipe(gulp.dest("css"));
});
```